# How does Rails go from an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound to a 404 error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, rails-activerecord

The Rails Guides' Action Controller Overview mentions in the section [Rescue](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rescue) that if an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception occurs and isn't handled, Rails knows to serve the user a 404:

> Rails' default exception handling displays a "500 Server Error"
>   message for all exceptions. If the request was made locally, a nice
>   traceback and some added information gets displayed so you can figure
>   out what went wrong and deal with it. If the request was remote Rails
>   will just display a simple "500 Server Error" message to the user, or
>   a "404 Not Found" if there was a routing error or a record could not
>   be found.

How does this happen? Which part of Rails catches the exception, and then chooses to serve a 404 Not Found?

Comment: If you are asking about which part of the Rails handles the exceptions, then it is the ***ActionController's Rescue middleware*** catches exceptions, and then tries to handle them.

Comment: http://www.monkeyandcrow.com/blog/reading_rails_handling_exceptions/

Answer (score 0):

well ActiveRecord is the model part, that manages the data…
the controller is responsible to broadcast the information.

So when the controller is receiving  a request, he asks the model "hey? do you have this resource?"

if the model says "no , don't have this", the controller translate this into an error 404. That's the role of the controller to make this understandable by external consumers of the system (API users for example, website,...)

Note Rails provide a default behaviour for both models and controllers, but those can be overridden to have a bespoke behaviour.